# how to receive link from database in flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, html, sql-server, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to receive a Youtube embeded video in my in my html document via Flask app,
so i have link of embeded video in database, And I am able to Fetch link But it is only in Text Format
Please help me for selecting right datatype in database

**Python Code:**

```
    class Youtube(db.Model):
        sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        embeded_video = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

@app.route("/videos/fixing")
def fixingpage():
    posts = Youtube.query.filter_by().all()
    return render_template('post.html', posts=posts)
```

**Html code (post.html) :**-

```
    <div>
{{ posts.embeded_video }}
    </div>
```

**Output :-**`It is printing as it is embeding link`

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OWN03n12VAc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

`Insted of it I want video to be Inserted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use safe

Html code (post.html) :-

```html
   <div>
    {{ posts.embeded_video | safe }}
    </div>
```